# How to remove only links, but not actual files?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, terminal, rm, svg

I have a folder full of .svg files, some of which are actual files and others are merely links to files. They both have the .svg file extension, however the actual files are labeled "SVG Image" and the links are labeled "Link to SVG Image". I only want to delete the links, but I can't rm *.svg because they both have the file extension .svg.
I can do `ls` and it shows the actual files vs symlinks in different colors so there is definitely a distinction. There are also far too many files to sort manually, which is why I want to be able to do this via a terminal command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bsh
cd /the/folder
find . -type l -name '*.svg' -print
# or
find . -type l -name '*.svg' -ls      # _not_ `-exec ls`
```

If that returns the right symbolic links

```bsh
find . -type l -name '*.svg' -delete
```

Comment: I strongly suggest further limiting with `-name '*.svg'`. For a quick optical check, I'd suggest using `find . -type l -name '*svg' -exec ls --color=yes '{}' +`. That way all links should have the typical cyan coloring, while proper svg-files should be purple. At least for standard `ls` implementations.

Comment: Thank @FelixJN, great suggestion

Comment: Could you please explain how this works for people don't understand terminal commands (such as myself)? Thanks!

Comment: I expanded the [`find` tag info page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/find/info) with a brief tutorial. Look there.